# js generatring a random number going up in 20s

Tags: javascript, math, random

I understand that you can create a random number via javascript with:

```
Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
```

the problem is i would like the numbers to go up in twenties, so like if it was a number between 0 and 100, the options would be 20, 40, 60, 80. Not sure if this is possible.

Comment: Get a random number between 1 and N and multiply by 20?

Comment: Thanks, I must be sleeping today :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Including zero:

```
20*Math.floor(Math.random()*5);
```

or from 20 to 80:

```
 20 + 20*Math.floor(Math.random()*4);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one.

```
(Math.floor(Math.random()*5)*20);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a more general function:

```
function randStep(min, max, step) {
    return min + (step * Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min)/step) );
}

// 0,20,40,60,80
var x = randStep(0, 100, 20);
```